# Display options for command at the prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, options

Is there a way to script any Linux commands to prompt the user for input?

For example:

`chage` has many options

```
Options:
  -d, --lastday LAST_DAY        set date of last password change to LAST_DAY
  -E, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -I, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -l, --list                    show account aging information
  -m, --mindays MIN_DAYS        set minimum number of days before password
                                change to MIN_DAYS
  -M, --maxdays MAX_DAYS        set maximim number of days before password
                                change to MAX_DAYS
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -W, --warndays WARN_DAYS      set expiration warning days to WARN_DAYS
```

I like to type in `chage` and get the above option and allow me to select one.  This will help me to remember all the options rather than having to type `chage -h` every time.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way to script a specific command? Yes.  Is there a way to generalize that to all commands? Not that I'm aware of.

That said, something that might help is `bash-completion`.  With that, you can type the command and a `-` followed by a double `tab` and see the list of options available.

```
$ chage --<tab><tab>
--expiredate  --inactive    --list        --mindays     --warndays
--help        --lastday     --maxdays     --root

$ chage <tab><tab>
<list of user names>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zsh has the `run-help` widget, by default bound to <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>, that will invoke the respective man page for the command at the prompt; eg.,

chage<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

will open `CHAGE(1)`.

quitting out of the man page will leave you back at the command prompt, ready to enter your options.

The widget is described in detail in `man zshcontrib`:

> Accessing On-Line Help
>          The  key sequence ESC h is normally bound by ZLE to execute the run-help widget (see zshzle(1)).  This invokes the run-help command
>   with the command word from the current input line as its argument.  By default, run-help is an alias for the man command, so this often fails when the command  word is a shell builtin or a user-defined function.  By redefining the run-help alias, one can improve the on-line help provided by the
>   shell.

As the man page notes, this widget is configurable to point to your own helpfiles (defined by `HELPDIR`), or others provided by the community.